# The Tate-Nakayama theorem and inflation

Tags: nt.number-theory, group-cohomology, class-field-theory, galois-cohomology

Let $K$ be a nonarchimedean local field,
and $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G={\rm Gal}(L/K)$ of order $n=[L:K]$.
By local class field theory, there is a canonical isomorphism
$$H^2(G,L^\times)\cong\frac{1}{n}{\Bbb Z}/{\Bbb Z}.$$
Let $u\in H^2(G,L^\times)$ be the *fundamental class*, that is, the generator corresponding to $\frac{1}{n}+{\Bbb Z}\in \frac{1}{n}{\Bbb Z}/{\Bbb Z}$.

Let $M$ be a torsion free $G$-module.
For $r\in{\Bbb Z}$, consider the cup product map
$$\alpha\colon H^r(G,M)\to H^{r+2}(G, M\otimes L^\times),\quad \xi \mapsto \xi\cup u.$$
By the Tate-Nakayama theorem, this map is an isomorphism.

Now let $L'\supset L\supset K$ be a larger finite Galois extension of $K$ with Galois group $G'={\rm Gal}(L'/K)$ of order $n'=[L':K]$.
We have a cup product isomorphism
$$\alpha'\colon H^r(G',M)\to H^{r+2}(G', M\otimes L^{\prime\,\times}),\quad \xi' \mapsto \xi'\cup u'$$
(where $u' \in H^2(G,L^{\prime\,\times})$ is the fundamental class),
and an inflation map
$$ {\rm Inf}\colon H^{r+2}(G, M\otimes L^\times)\to H^{r+2}(G', M\otimes L^{\prime\,\times}).$$

> **Question.** What is the map marked with "?" making commutative the following diagram:
> $\require{AMScd}$
> \begin{CD}
> H^r(G,M) @>\alpha>>   H^{r+2}(G', M\otimes L^{\times})\\
> @V?VV                                 @VV{\rm Inf}V \\
> H^r(G',M) @>\alpha'>>   H^{r+2}(G', M\otimes L^{\prime\,\times})
> \end{CD}

Note that ${\rm Inf}(u)=(n'/n)\cdot u'$.

I expect that the map
$$ H^r(G,M) \overset?\longrightarrow H^r(G',M)$$
is just the inflation map induced by the surjective homomorphism $G'\to G$, but I cannot prove that.